# What should I name the keybinding menu?

Tags: user-experience, ui-design

Here's a pretty basic question:

My game supports custom keybindings. What label should I put on the button the player clicks to get to the menu that lets him customize them?

Specifically, this game is targeted at nerdy high-schoolers to nerdy middle-aged adults, and any given player may or may not be an experienced gamer, or even if they are they may or may not be familiar with first person shooters, where I imagine the idea of custom key bindings is usually first encountered.

I need a name that doesn't feel out of place in my menu (which consists of short two-word labels: "Start Game," "Load Game," "Level Select, "Save & Quit," etc...) but conveys the idea of "this is where you go to alter which buttons do what" without using semi-advanced gamer jargon like "bind" or "mapping."

Any suggestions?